# Bootstrap 5 - Background Cover Image With Transparant Overlay Content

Tags: css, image, responsive, bootstrap-5

I am currently trying to code a frontpage according [this design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwDI8.png), using bootstrap 5. I've managed to set the background to cover the entire page. However, I can't seem to get the white transparent overlay-block right, and the placing of the content inside. This should also be responsive according to [this design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICdxA.png).

Whats the best solution for doing this?

Currently I've got:

**Startpage html**

```
<div class="startpage">
    <div class="hero">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-7 offset-md-1">
                    <h1 class="pb-2 pb-md-4">Heading Title</h1>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary mt-3" type="button">Button Title</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Startpage css**

```
.startpage {
   height: 100vh;
   background: url(URL HERE);
   background-attachment: fixed;
   background-position: center;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: cover;
}

.hero {
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(250, 250, 250, 0.95), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8));
    min-height: 70%;
    padding-top: 200px;
}
```

**On the navbar I've got:**

```
header {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks if you can edit your post to include any code you are using. This helps people to work out an answer for you. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You need to set `height: 100%;` instead of `min-height: 70%;` in .hero. & then check it.

Comment: I can see your background is overlayed by this `background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(250, 250, 250, 0.95), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8));`
 To resolve this issue, remove the background image of a hero. Next, you can add this `.startpage {
   height: 100vh;
   background-image: liner-gradient(linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,.1), rgba(255, 255, 255, .3)) url(URL HERE);
   background-position: center center;
   background-size: cover;
}`